# Issue with find: invalid predicate '-delete'

Tags: windows-7, bash, unix, shell

I try to run (unix-shell, win7):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -size -50k -delete
```

and get the error:

```
find: invalid predicate '-delete'
```

any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may also find the [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) is helpful, not only in find & delete operations, but, in others where you may want to process text after you run a command. In this case,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -size -50k | xargs rm -f
```

Always make sure you check your work with an "echo" before xargs, first (so you can see what the commands look like before you run it). Which would look like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -size -50k | xargs echo rm -f
```

Comment: The version with `echo` won't include the files found by `find`; it ignores the input and echoes the literal string 'xargs rm -f'.

Comment: Thanks - xargs is the slickest, I guess.. One thing though: how to include filenames with spaces. `IFS=$'\t\n'` didn't work for me.. And, would there be a command that puts the files to the bin, instead of deleting them permanentely?

Comment: @Kay -- No prob! For the spaces, what you'll want to do is position the argument in xargs with the "-i" flag. Like...

`find . | xargs -i rm -f "{}"`

So -i says "I'm going to posItion the argument" and the {} says "Here's where I want to position it". Then the quote to tell your shell "Hey man, there's junk in this thing, so, yeah just take the stuff in the quotes".

Comment: @Chepner -- oops! I had the `echo` in the wrong place. I moved it, it should work as I meant it, now.

Comment: @Kay -- reread, about putting them in a bin, I'd move them to /tmp. You can do the same thing using the position, like.... `find . | xargs -i mv "{}" /tmp/`

Answer (score 6):

The version of `find` found from the unix shell you are running (from windows) lacks the 
`-delete` predicate.

An possible alternative is-:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -size -50k -exec rm {} \;
```